# VIS JS: Cant make network fit bootstrap panel

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, jinja2, vis.js

I am working with [vis.JS](http://visjs.org/) to create a network graph from some data. Then I populate this network within a bootstrap panel. The issue is that the network is very small. I can't make any sense of it. Also, if I zoom in, I loose all perspective of the data.

[image]

Here are the code snippets

the div where the network appears

```
<div class="row">
<div class="panel panel-primary" >
    <div class="panel-heading">Heading</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="network" width=100% height=100%></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and here is the javascript. Note that my data is coming from server via Jinja

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// create an array with nodes
var mynodes = new vis.DataSet({{ mynodes | safe }});

// create an array with edges
var myedges = new vis.DataSet({{ myedges |safe }});

// create a network
var container = document.getElementById('network');
var data = {
    nodes: mynodes,
    edges: myedges
};
var options = {
    autoResize: true,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
};
var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
</script>
```

How can I set the size of the network that appears? Ideally I want to size the network so that the nodes and edges are legible.

What am I missing? Is it because of bootstrap that I am not able to resize the network properly?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]: substitute the jinja template parts with some data that's good enough to reproduce the issue and more importantly, we need CSS to see what actually happens. Please consider creating SO snippet or jsFilddle and I'm sure we'll solve this issue. Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the solution

```
var options = {
              width: '1000px',
              height: '600px'
              };
```

Comment: please accept your answer so that it's clear that the issue is solved